# How To merge two divs to one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two divs

```
<div id = "first">some details111</div>
```

and

```
<div id = "second">some details222</div>
```

I want to create:

```
<div id ="New">some details111 some details222</div>
```

What is the best and the fast way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Using jQuery you could do that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").append("<div id='New'></div>");
   $("#New").text($("#first").text() + " " +$("#second").text());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Some vanilla JS for kicks and giggles:

```
// grab the content from our two divs
var content1 = document.getElementById('one').innerHTML;
var content2 = document.getElementById('two').innerHTML;

// create our new div, pop the content in it, and give it an id
var combined = document.createElement('div');
combined.innerHTML = content1 + " " + content2; // a little spacing
combined.id = 'new';

// 'container' can be whatever your containing element is
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(combined);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below :

Fiddle Example : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/99/

If you **already have a DIV** with ID "NEW" then try like below:

```
$('#New').html($('#first').html() + " " + $('#second').html())
```

If you **want to Create a div** and then add the Content then try like below.

```
$("body").append("<div id ='New'></div>")
$('#New').html($('#first').html() + " " + $('#second').html())
```

Comment: That wouldn't work, since `$('New')` would try to select an element (and fail), not create a new one.

Comment: Same issue, the `div id="New">` element doesn't exist; you're still trying (incorrectly) to select an existing element, you're not creating a new one.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist : Is this the change your asking...? Now the code is ok...?

Answer (score 0):

Well, using jQuery you can do by this way:

```
$("body").append(
    $('<div/>')
        .attr("id","New")
        .html(
            $("#first).html() + $("#second").html()
        )
);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. How I see It creates me new div but how I erase the old one ?

Comment: `$("#first,#second").remove()`;

Answer (score 0):

```
$("&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;").attr("id", "New").html($("#first").html() + $("#second").html()).appendTo($("body"));
```